# Aggregating variables with similar first digit

Tags: statistics, stata

In the table below each item has a 2-digit code. The first digit signifies a category.

[image: First table]

I want to aggregate the items with the same first digit per person using Stata. Thus, the solution will be:

[image: Solution]

In this table, item1 = item11+item14+item15+item17 and item2=item21+item25 that are calculated per person.

Comment: Presenting data as images that can't be copied easily is poor practice. Please present data as code.

Comment: Spelling is Stata. https://www.statalist.org/forums/help#spelling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
clear 
input str1 person item11 item21 item14 item15 item25 item17
a 2 3 5 1 3 50
end 

egen item1 = rowtotal(item1*) 
egen item2 = rowtotal(item2*)

drop item1? item2? 
list 

     +------------------------+
     | person   item1   item2 |
     |------------------------|
  1. |      a      58       6 |
     +------------------------+
```