# Calculating one mean and standard deviation for multiple variables

Tags: statistics, stata, mean

Please consider the following table:

[image]

I want to calculate the mean and standard deviation for all observations using Stata. Stata can measure mean and standard deviation for each variable and observation; however, finding mean and standard deviation for all observations is not straightforward. How can I generate the mean and standard deviation of all data?
Using Excel, the mean and standard deviation of this table are **4.2** and **3.286** respectively.

Comment: Comments on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70041484/aggregating-variables-with-similar-first-digit apply here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
clear 
input str1 person item11 item21 item14 item15 item25 
a 2 3 5 1 3 50
b 3 10 2 7 14 
c 7 3 1 4 2 
d 4 2 6 1 4 
end 

mata 
data = st_data(., "item*")
mean(vec(data)), sqrt(variance(vec(data)))
end
```

Stata prints out 4.2   3.286335345.

EDIT Here is a version that exports scalars back to Stata.

```
clear 
input str1 person item11 item21 item14 item15 item25 
a 2 3 5 1 3 50
b 3 10 2 7 14 
c 7 3 1 4 2 
d 4 2 6 1 4 
end 

mata 
data = st_data(., "item*")
mean = mean(vec(data)); sd = sqrt(variance(vec(data)))
mean, sd 
st_numscalar("mean", mean) 
st_numscalar("sd", sd)
end 

di scalar(mean)
di scalar(sd)
```

Comment: Thanks, Nick, it works. The question is how can I save the results to use them in a formula?

Comment: You can export from Mata as a local macro or scalar, for example. See help on Stata interface functions in Mata.

Comment: See now extended answer.

Answer (score 2):

If all observations need to be considered, perhaps as long format is more useful format. (Thanks to Nick for the data example)

```
clear 
input str1 person bread vegatable fruit meat soda
a 2 3 5 1 3 
b 3 10 2 7 14 
c 7 3 1 4 2 
d 4 2 6 1 4 
end 

ds person, not
rename (`r(varlist)') val=

reshape long val, i(person) j(item) string
sum val
```